# How to merge rows in the attribute table while adding up one column

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I intersected two layers and now I would like to merge the rows that have the same id while adding up the last column using QGIS.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox /Aggregate` and set `Group by expression (NULL to group all features)` to the field containing the information about the group to which should be merged and the `Umfang` field to `sum` - in general, check for each field the aggregated value you want to get:

[image]

You get a new layer as result: a copy of your input layer, but with a reduced no. of features and aggregated values as you defined it in the dialog:

[image]